# The efficient way to compare value between two cell and assign value based on condition in Numpy

Tags: pandas, performance, numpy

The objective is to count the frequency when two nodes have similar value.

Say, for example, we have a vector

```
pd.DataFrame([0,4,1,1,1],index=['A','B','C','D','E'])
```

as below

```
   0
A  0
B  4
C  1
D  1
E  1
```

And, the element Nij is equal to 1 if nodes i and j have similar value and is equal to zero otherwise.

N is then

```
    A   B   C   D   E
A   1   0   0   0   0
B   0   1   0   0   0
C   0   0   1   1   1
D   0   0   1   1   1
E   0   0   1   1   1
```

This simple example can be extended to 2D. For example, here create array of shape (4,5)

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  4  1  1  1
2  0  1  1  2  2
3  0  3  2  2  2
```

Similarly, we go row wise and set the element Nij is equal to 1 if nodes i and j have similar value and is equal to zero otherwise. At every iteration of the row, we sum the cell value.

The frequency is then equal to

```
     A    B    C    D    E
A  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B  1.0  4.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
C  1.0  2.0  4.0  3.0  3.0
D  1.0  1.0  3.0  4.0  4.0
E  1.0  1.0  3.0  4.0  4.0
```

Based on this, the following code is proposed. But, the current implementation used 3 for-loops and some if-else statement.

I am curios whether the code below can be enhanced further, or maybe, there is a build-in method within Pandas or Numpy that can be used to achieve similar objective.

```py
import numpy as np
    
arr=[[ 0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,4,1,1,1],
    [0,1,1,2,2],
    [0,3,2,2,2]]
arr=np.array(arr)
# C=arr

# nrows
npart = len(arr[:,0])

# Ncolumns
m = len(arr[0,:])
X = np.zeros(shape =(m,m), dtype = np.double)
for i in range(npart):
    for k in range(m):
        for p in range(m):

                # Check whether the pair have similar value or not
                if arr[i,k] == arr[i,p]:
                    X[k,p] = X[k,p] + 1
                else:
                    X[k,p] = X[k,p] + 0
```

Output:

```
4.00000,1.00000,1.00000,1.00000,1.00000
1.00000,4.00000,2.00000,1.00000,1.00000
1.00000,2.00000,4.00000,3.00000,3.00000
1.00000,1.00000,3.00000,4.00000,4.00000
1.00000,1.00000,3.00000,4.00000,4.00000
```

p.s. The index A,B,C,D,E and use of pandas are for clarification purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With numpy, you can use broadcasting:

#### 1D

```
a = np.array([0,4,1,1,1])
(a==a[:, None])*1
```

output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

#### 2D

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 4, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
              [0, 3, 2, 2, 2]])

(a.T == a.T[:,None]).sum(2)
```

output:

```
array([[4, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 4, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 4, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 3, 4, 4],
       [1, 1, 3, 4, 4]])
```

Comment: Awesome, this is much better  than originally proposed above

Comment: @rpb be aware that broadcasting can consume a lot of memory (square of the original data), so this only works with reasonably sized data (or a lot of memory) ;)

Comment: Compare to the originally proposed above, does the difference in memory consumption is significant. For my used case, the array shape can be up to (256 256).

Comment: No problem, numpy can handle millions of cells. It might be an issue if you have several thousands rows/columns.